# Getting attribute error on non-attribute variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Im working on a game and getting a strange error where instance variable isn't saved properly (as far as I can tell). This happens when i try to access self.game from the RunGame instance. By the way the classes are in separate modules, and im not showing all code. The game runs fine, but when switching level it just crashes

```
class RunGame(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.makeTk()
        self.currentLevel = 0
        self.bricksLayout = [            #for debugging: a layout of bricks. 3d array with each level
            [
                    [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
                    [0,0,0,0,4,1,1,1],
                    [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
                ],

                [
                    [4,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
                    [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
                ]

            ]

        self.game = GameInstance(self.bricksLayout,self)
        self.game.run = False       #this does nothing for some reason, no error though

    def switchLevel(self):
        print("switching level")
        self.game.run = False       #calling this will give no attribute error

        #self.game.clearCanvas()
        #self.game.canvas.destroy()
        self.currentLevel+=1
        #self.game = Game(self.bricksLayout,self)

    def makeTk(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("PrakeOut")
        self.screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth();  #monitor size
        self.screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight();
        #root.wm_attributes("-fullscreen",True)     #this gives fullscreen, but removes the menu
        self.root.resizable(0,0) #cant be resized
        self.root.configure(background="Black")      #bg color of root windw
        #root.geometry("%ix%i+0+0" % (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))  #maximizes screen. First two are width and height, other two are x1 and y1
        #root.wm_attributes("-topmost",1);   #places window in foreground   

run = RunGame()

class GameInstance(object):


    def __init__(self, bricksLayout,gameHandler):
        self.bricksLayout = bricksLayout
        self.gameHandler = gameHandler
        self.run = True     #game loop

        self.makeCanvas()

        self.brickList = []    #the list of all da created bricks
        self.makeBricks()
        self.makeBallAndPaddle()

        self.gameLoop()
        self.root.mainloop();    #needs to run main loop otherwise windows doesnt show
```

It gives this error:

File "C:\Users\Bollen\Desktop\python projects\breakout\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\GameHandler.py", line 30, in switchLevel
    self.game.run = False       #calling this will give no attribute error
AttributeError: 'RunGame' object has no attribute 'game'
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: The code you posted cannot give the error you say it does, because it has other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use your code to reproduce the problem, but there is one very obvious logic error in your code. The problem is that neither of your classes is allowed to be fully created before they are being used.

Take a look at `GameInstance`: because you call `mainloop` within the initializer, that class will never be fully instantiated until after the root window has been created *and then destroyed*. Therefore, any other classes which try to work with this instance will be working with a not-fully-formed instance.

Likewise, with `GameRunner` you are creating an instance of `GameInstance`. Because `GameInstance` calls `mainloop`, the creation of the `GameRunner` object cannot be finished before `GameInstance` has been created, and `GameInstance` won't be finished until the window is destroyed.

The first step is to remove the call to `mainloop` from `GameInstance.__init__`. Instead, move that into a method that `GameRunner` can call once it is fully created.

You should also separate the creation of the two objects into two steps. Your main logic would then look something like the following./ I'm not sure if you should create the runner first or the game first, but either way is acceptable depending on how you define the classes.

```
game = GameInstance(...)
runner = GameRunner(..., game)
runner.run()
```

In the above, runner.run() would look something like this:

```
class GameRunner(...):
    def run(self):
        self.game.run()
```

... and game.run would look like this:

```
class GameInstance(...):
    def run(self):
        self.gameLoop()
        self.root.mainloop()
```